# Docker Apache - safe to chown /usr/local/apache2 to non-root user?

Tags: linux, apache, docker

I would like to run the [official Docker Apache image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) as a non-root user. To make it work, it seems like it is necessary to `chown` the `/usr/local/apache2` directory (see [this](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/issues/102#issuecomment-404115726) and [this](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/issues/118#issue-381101601)):

```
chown -hR appuser:appuser /usr/local/apache2
```

`appuser` is the non-root user (group) in this case.

Originally, the files and directories in `/usr/local/apache2` are owned by root. How safe is it, to give ownership of these files and directories to a normal user? Does this pose a security risk?

```
/usr/local/apache2/
├── bin/
├── build/
├── cgi-bin/
├── conf/
├── error/
├── htdocs/
├── icons/
├── include/
├── logs/
└── modules/
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no security concern running it as a non-root user that I know of.  If this were my deployment I would recommend it.  You will run into complications trying to use ports below 1024 as a non-root user, but that is easily remedied.  I have seen the method used that you're suggesting in the question.  I also found this [method](https://takac.dev/docker-run-apache-as-non-root-user-based-on-the-official-image/), which I haven't tried yet but looks promising.  FYI, how you manage your Docker server is even more important.  Check the CIS Docker Hardening Benchmarks for details.